# modify a button onclick in a custom listView

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I've made a custom ListView and i would like to be able to click on a small button or on the whole row. So im making 2 seperate  onclicklisteners for the 2 cases. How do i reference the button? it gives me this error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable viewHolder inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

I cant make it final because it changes continuously.
Here is my code.

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public Context context; 
        public int layoutResourceId;
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;
        public Bitmap icon;
        private static int REFRESH_THRESHOLD = 2;

        //public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int listviewItemRow, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items, Bitmap icon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, listviewItemRow);
            this.items = items;
            this.context = context;
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public Item getItem(Item position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            if (row == null) {

                inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);       

                viewHolder.ic_thumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ic_thumbnail);
                viewHolder.scadenza = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvScadenza);
                viewHolder.prezzo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvPrezzo);
                viewHolder.followers = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowers);
                viewHolder.hProgressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.hProgressBar);
                viewHolder.followButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnFollow);

                row.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            HashMap<String, Object> item = items.get(position);
            viewHolder.ic_thumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.get("pic1m"));
            viewHolder.scadenza.setText((CharSequence) item.get("scadenza"));
            viewHolder.prezzo.setText((CharSequence) item.get("prezzo"));
            viewHolder.followers.setText((CharSequence) item.get("followers"));
            viewHolder.hProgressBar.setProgress((Integer) item.get("coefficient"));
            viewHolder.followButton.setText("non segui");
            viewHolder.followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
//here i get the error
                    viewHolder.followButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.drawable.action_object_button_gray);
                    followButton.setText("segui");
                }
            });


            row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));


            return row;
        }

        private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

            private int mPosition;

            private OnItemClickListener(int position){
                mPosition = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("onListItemClickList", "Item clicked: " + mPosition);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Message " + Integer.toString(mPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DettagliActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", mPosition);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }   
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView prezzo;
            public TextView scadenza;
            public TextView followers;
            public ImageView ic_thumbnail;
            public ProgressBar hProgressBar;
            public Button followButton;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to define ViewHolder  as final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
viewHolder.followButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.drawable.action_object_button_gray);
followButton.setText("segui");
```

You can use

```
Buttom button =(Button)v; // casting view to button
button.setText("segui");  // set text to button
```

If you are using a variable in a anonymous inner class it is required that the variable be final.

Reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

[Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Comment: @Pheonix7 to understand why the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: +1 because of the references and spreading of knowledge. Very, very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the onClickListener on the button you're interested in, why not just cast the view to a button and modify it using the view parameter?

```
viewHolder.followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
//here i get the error
                    Button view = (Button) v;
                    view.setText("segui");
                }
            });
```

Comment: it gives me error so i used

View view = (Button) v;
    ((Button) view).setText("segui");


now it works for me

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is

```
final ViewHolder temp = viewHolder;
```

and use that.